# Proper way to get unsigned angles between 0 and 180 for histogram of gradients

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

Currently I have code that computes the magnitude and orientation from the Sobel dervatives.

```
mag, ang = cv2.cartToPolar(gx, gy, angleInDegrees=True)
ang = ang.clip(min=0, max=179.99999)
```

Long story short, how can I force angles to be unsigned and between [0, 180) degrees without clipping which seems to screw up the histogram distribution.

Is there a numpy function that would take a angle greater than 180, for example 200, and split out 160 or do I have to code something like that up myself.

Would it be possibly to makes the numpy array only contain values from -180 to 180 and then I could just take the abs value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `ang = ang.clip(min=0, max=179.99999)`, use

```
ang = ang % 180
```

`%` is the [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) in Python.
This converts, for example, -135 to 45, which I suspect is what you want.  That is, both those angles correspond to a line with slope 1.

Comment: For radians, would it work to do ` ang = ang % pi/2 `?